Render is really bright but it's fine in viewport
New to blender, I've followed a mishmash of tutorials so I'm really struggling
I was playing with some settings (added some lights, and tried to change vbr) and managed to mess up my render AND save over it, so I can't revert.
Anyone got any ideas of what to try?


your viewport is in shader view (which has own lights except you changed that what i don't believe) and your render is then different. So to see the result which looks "more like" render choose viewport shading -> rendered


Anyone got any ideas of what to try?

If your lights are too bright, the thing to try is obviously lowering the intensity of your lights. It's really that simple. That would be the Power property of your light object in this case:

Keep in mind you may have different light sources in your scene as well like world lighting. You can access it in the World tab in the Properties Editor or in the Shader Editor, World mode:

As for differences in render and viewport I have no idea where this expectation of them matching comes from. It's not the first time I see it, but you really should not have such an expectation. There would be no need for rendering, if everything could be shown in the viewport the way it is supposed to look. Rendering will usually calculate a lot of aspects of the image in more precision and it must look different from the viewport you use to work with your scene faster( you could use rendered view in the viewport as well, but that might make things slower, less stable and less convenient to work with). It is perfectly normal that you need to test things out with test renders and adjust your results. This is very common in pretty much any CG workflow involving rendering. You test it and adjust as needed. This should be expected. Viewport is just a representation of your scene similar to what you will get when rendering.
